# Polymer - bubbleEvent is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, polymer

I know this is a newb question, but I just don't understand and neither do other similar questions help on this site...

So I have a Polymer object and I'm doing:

```
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, () => {
      this.addSubComponentEventListeners();
      this.addEventListener('connection-type-changed', (e) => {
        this.bubbleEvent(e);
      });
    });
  }

  addSubComponentEventListeners() {
   //adding stuff
  }

  bubbleEvent(e) {
    console.log(`Bubblin': ${e}`);
    this.fire(e);
  }
```

For some reason that I cannot understand, even though I have both of the functions declared on the same scope, however `addSubComponentEventListeners` runs without a problem and I get an error for `bubbleEvent` saying `this.bubbleEvent() is not a function`. Can someone please explain how it's not a function? Is it on a different scope? Why? How to make it run?

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to do there and why.. but just about the question.. did you try to log `this. bubbleEvent` and see what it is? Maybe it's a property,  not a function..

Comment: I'm trying to bubble up a property-changed event (these do not bubble by default so I need to do it by hand). How is it a property if I defined it as a function and am also calling it as a function?

Comment: I'm not saying that it is, I am saying that *maybe* it is.. it might not be the case.. but something else could define a property with the same name.. based on the error message itself that is one possibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function#Function_shares_a_name_with_a_pre-existing_property

Comment: Can you edit this [demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/KGrJgP?editors=1010) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: have you tried to log this.bubleEvent? It is maybe undefined.. have you tried to rename the function to some different name? there might be some other property that rewrites your function..

Comment: Seems like a scoping problem. Try to print the value of `this` right before you call `bubbleEvent` and see if it's actually your Polymer element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.bubbleEvent` is in an anonymous function, so I make the assumption that you're in the wrong scope. Try binding the function.

```
 this.addEventListener('connection-type-changed', (e) => {
    this.bubbleEvent(e);
  }.bind(this));
```